# how to read external file by reference (at runtime)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have an application built with vue cli (webpack) and there is a json file that is in an outside folder of my project.

```
-file.json
-aplicationVue
  -public
  -src
  -babel.config.js
  -package.json
  -vue.config.js
  -...
```

The file.json file has one variable that is dynamically modified by another application. Within my vue application I need to read this file.json file and get the data. That is, when the webpack builds the application I need to use a file.json file reference instead of reading the file.json file and get the result.

I'm using the required ('path / file'), but when building the application with the webpack, the contents of file.json is read and not your reference.

How can I import an external file inside the vue cli (which use the webpack) so that the application reads the external file at runtime?

Comment: For reading the file at runtime, you need to send a request to your server.